# Create git project in git project (no submodule)

Tags: git, versioning

I'm using git and I'm working on a library for an embedded project. The library shall be usable by other projects too, so I decided to create a new project and link the lib to my main project via git's submodule feature.
No problem so far.

But, as this is an embedded project, I have to add additional code, like hardware initialization and system timer. However, these stuff should not be in the library's project, because its not necessary for running the lib, only for developing it. Let's call this stuff development harness.

So, this means my actual lib folder is a git project INSIDE a bigger project, the development harness.
Looks like:

```
/ development harness root
|-- .git
|-- makefile
|-- main.c
|-- additional_stuff.c
|-- lib folder (can be used from someone else as submodule)
         |-- .git
         |-- lib.c
         |-- lib.h
```

So, the "inner project" can be used by other, external projects via submodule feature.
The outer project (the development harness) will help me to develop my lib, build it and run it on the hardware.

However, my problem is: how do I create such a structure?
How do I tell the outer project that there is an inner project, whose single files should not be tracked?
I tried just to "git init" inside my lib folder, and this will indeed create a inner project, but the files are also being tracked by the outer project.
I guess, .gitignore is wrong in this place.

I also cannot create the inner project as a submodule, because this project is not existing anywhere at the moment. But "git submodule add" does require a repository/path to an existing project.

One solution I can think of is something like this:

```
/ development harness root
|-- .git
|-- makefile
|-- main.c
|-- additional_stuff.c
|-- lib folder (via submodule feature)
     |-- (all stuff here is pulled from lib root)

/ lib root
|-- .git
|-- lib.c
|-- lib.h
```

I guess this might work.
But, for me it feels false. This will give me another "top level project". If I would do this for all kind of stuff which might be reused sometimes, I will have lots of projects...
Furthermore, for me this is not even a real project, because it's not build- and runnable.

So, is there a way to achieve a structure like in my first example?

Answer (score 0):

What about having a completely separated repo for your library, and using it as a library in your main project?

This way, in your lib repo you can have

- your library code
- your development harness (it won't bother your clients since they could use your library as e.g. a `.so`, i.e. without manipulating the code)

and in your main repo you just need to reference this library in your build files.

It might be less practical than using submodules if you plan to often change both your library and your main project at the same time. But if you have a code cleanly decoupled, it should, imo, be the way to go.

Comment: Please don't tell me how you would do that. There are many reasons why not to ship a binary library (.so), exspecially for embedded projects. So, once again, is it possible to achieve the folder structure of my first example (git project inside git project)?